# Is there a way to customize the times shown in the Bootstrap DateTimePicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am looking into using the Bootstrap DateTimePicker for scheduling appointments, and I was wondering if there is a way to customize the times that are shown?

For example, after you click on September 11, 2018, it will take you to the time selection. I want it to show only my available times for the day (say 10:30, 14:45, 15:00) instead of 15 minute increments.

Is this possible from either the front- or -back-end?
Thanks!

**Edit:** If there's a way to customize if from the front-end, I can figure it out on the back-end. I'm just not really sure if this is even possible.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using this library - according to the docs: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disabledtimeintervals

Comment: Hi, would you please edit your questions tags? Neither C# nor asp.net are relevant. Maybe you want to add one of the `bootstrap` tags, but you did not mentioned the version you are using.

Comment: @user1934587390 I see how the en/disable hour could be useful, but I don;t see where I can add my own times or only enable specific times (14:30, 9:15).